# Can't serialize JSON properly using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization, json.net

I using JSON.net to convert very complex XML to JSON and deserialize it to C#.

```
string text = await blockBlob2.DownloadTextAsync();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(text);
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

RootObject x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
```

I faced with issue with "@" symbols ocurring in JSON after conversion from XML. When I try to serialize it, all structure is works, but field's content become null.
[image: @ added after automatically, I don't know why]

and then SerializeObject doesn't work properly: [image]

RootObjectClass:

```
    /* 
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace WorkerRole1
{

    public class ItineraryOption
    {
        public string ODRef { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string SeatsAvailable { get; set; }
        public string TravelTime { get; set; }
        public string ItineraryRef { get; set; }
        public object FlightSegment { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItineraryOptions
    {
        public List<ItineraryOption> ItineraryOption { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookingGuidelines
    {
        public string RussianNamesSupported { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeepLink
    {
        public string DeviceType { get; set; }
        //public string __invalid_name__#cdata-section { get; set; }
   // public string __invalid_name__#text { get; set; }
}

    public class DeepLinks
    {
        public List<DeepLink> DeepLink { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShopOption
    {
        public string OptionRef { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string Total { get; set; }
        public string Airlines { get; set; }
        public ItineraryOptions ItineraryOptions { get; set; }
        public BookingGuidelines BookingGuidelines { get; set; }
        public DeepLinks DeepLinks { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShopOptions
    {
        public List<ShopOption> ShopOption { get; set; }
    }

    public class SIGAirShopRS
    {
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
        public string ProcessingTime { get; set; }
        public string SIGVersion { get; set; }
        public string SchemaVersion { get; set; }
        public string BuildDate { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public ShopOptions ShopOptions { get; set; }
    }

    public class SIGResponse
    {
        public string xmlns { get; set; }
        public SIGAirShopRS SIG_AirShopRS { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public SIGResponse SIG_Response { get; set; }
    }

}
```

sample of XML:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CEquA-V15lamN5UVRWeDdzR2M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: add your RootObject class and example data

Comment: Why go to JSON then to a C# object instead of XML directly to objects?

Comment: Is the problem you have caused by the "@" sign? In case you are not sure your should double check this and then probably "escape" the character.

Comment: it's neccesary to convert for future using. added class

Comment: found workaround, not sure it's best way:XmlDocument doc = new 
                json=json.Replace("@", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest marking up the properties in your `RootObject` class with `JsonPropertyAttribute` and explicitly set the name for the auto-generated "@" property names in the Json to your local class property names e.g:

```
public string xmlns {get;set;}
```

..becomes..

```
[JsonProperty("@xmlns")]
public string xmlns {get;set;}
```

According to the NewtonSoft JSON C# Deserialization samples, a normal POCO object would NOT generate the @ style names for properties in JSON but I suspect it's because you are converting from XML (`xmlns` for example is an XML **at**tribute normally).

Also the `Result` property serializes fine and you'll notice it's the only JSON property not prefixed by "@".

Comment: big thank you guy, i'll check it. I found another workaround - 
                json=json.Replace("@", "");   but it's bad idea to do my way =)

Comment: Not a problem. Please mark my answer as correct if it's solved your issue. :)

Comment: Also, it would only be bad if you don't plan on taking the JSON back to XML, I think. Otherwise, less maintenance of all those attributes!